# Use RegExp to restrict input data

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to force the user to enter a password with exact number of caracts.
The password have to be like that :
8 total caracts :
1 (exactly) uppercase,
3 (exactly) numbers
and lowercases (4 in that case).

The regex i have : `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]{1})(?=.*[0-9]{3})`

The problem is we can put more than 3 numb and more then 1 uper and more than 8 caract..

Examples :

- 5p23qPsb -> OK
- I9Opdi90 -> NOT OK
- h7y1Rdw6 -> OK
- IUD8954r -> NOT OK

An idea or some help ?
Thanks (I'm french so sorry for my english..)

Comment: I would replace the regex by „manually“ analysing the password in your script. Like: count uppercases, count numbers, etc. (I don't post this with a example as a answer because you ask explicit for a solution with regex in your title.)

Comment: `[0-9]{3}` means three digits in a row not three digits in total.

Comment: It's a good solution for the moment, Thank you,

Comment: Do not use a regex for this task, just use senden9's approach. Something like `s.match(/[a-z]/g).length == 4 && s.match(/[A-Z]/g).length == 1 && s.match(/\d/g).length` (add error checking).

Comment: Blech.  This seems like the sort of thing regular expressions are suited for.  You have a string and you want to make sure it matches a certain format.  You don't have to cheapen them.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely on the right track with this.  You are stacking lookaheads, but lookaheads don't actually *match* anything.  They just check to make sure that it can complete a match.  So you'll need to add something like a `.+` for it to actually match on.  Here is a workdown on how you can validate your string.

Let's start with the entire string.  We want it to be exactly 8 characters, so we can do something like this:

```
^(?=.{8}$)
```

Then, we want exactly one uppercase letter, so we can make a lookahead like this:

```
(?=.*[A-Z])
```

Next, we want to require exactly one digit, so we can use this:

```
(?=.*[0-9])
```

Finally, we want to require exactly 4 lowercase letters that may or may not be next to each other.  Here's a lookahead that matches that:

```
(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z])
```

Now that we've got all of the pieces, we can set our actual expression to match any character, more than one time `.+`.  The previous lookaheads will make sure it fits the requirements.  Piecing everything together, we end up with an expression like this:

```
^(?=.{8}$)(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).+
```

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/nFfTvu/1)

Comment: Thank you for all those informations !
I keep your answer for future cases :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 /(?=.*?[A-Z]{1})(?=.*?[a-z]{4})(?=.*?[0-9]{3})/.test("123Aacds");
```